# In SQL Server, how do I generate a CREATE TABLE statement for a given table?

Tags: sql-server, scripting, dynamic-sql

I've spent a good amount of time coming up with solution to this problem, so in the spirit of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245/questions-vs-conveying-information), I'm posting it here, since I think it might be useful to others.

If anyone has a better script, or anything to add, please post it.

Edit: Yes guys, I know how to do it in Management Studio - but I needed to be able to do it from within another application.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I've modified the version above to run for all tables and support new SQL 2005 data types.  It also retains the primary key names.  Works only on SQL 2005 (using cross apply).

```
select  'create table [' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'ALTER TABLE ' + so.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')' END
from    sysobjects so
cross apply
    (SELECT 
        '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
        data_type + case data_type
            when 'sql_variant' then ''
            when 'text' then ''
            when 'ntext' then ''
            when 'xml' then ''
            when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
            else coalesce('('+case when character_maximum_length = -1 then 'MAX' else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end +')','') end + ' ' +
        case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=so.name
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
        ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
         (case when UPPER(IS_NULLABLE) = 'NO' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
          case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT ELSE '' END + ', ' 

     from information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name
     order by ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)
left join
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
on  tc.Table_name       = so.Name
AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
cross apply
    (select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
     FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     WHERE  kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
     ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION
     FOR XML PATH('')) j (list)
where   xtype = 'U'
AND name    NOT IN ('dtproperties')
```

**Update:** Added handling of the XML data type

**Update 2:** Fixed cases when 1) there is multiple tables with the same name but with different schemas, 2) there is multiple tables having PK constraint with the same name

Comment: This is fantastic! I've been looking for something like this for quite some time! (trying to script table structure into our version control)

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  I think you should be using the numeric_precision column, not numeric_precision_radix, and in addition to the decimal datatype, it should work the same for the numeric datatype.

Comment: I think you have an error -- numeric_precision_radix should be numeric_precision

Comment: I noticed when running this that the output has a extra comma at the end when listing the columns. I was able to remove the extra comma by surrounding the o.list in line 1 with `STUFF(o.list,1,2,'')` and moving the comma from the end of the cross apply on line 23 to the start in line 5  `',  ['+column_name+'] ' + `

Comment: With @Imingle change I also changed `LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1)` to  `STUFF(j.List, 1,2,'')` and moved the comma on line 33 to the front `select ', [' + Column_Name + '] '`

Comment: Just to note that this query does not show partitions if any available.

Comment: This looks great, only change I would make is to add some line breaks to make the output more readable, but if your just doing this from code then these arn't needed.

Comment: This preserves original collation:
`+ CASE WHEN t1.COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + t1.COLLATION_NAME ELSE '' END`

Comment: Does that really work with same object names in different schemas/catalogs? For example `from information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name` is not schema aware.

Comment: Would be good if there is a version that does not use the sysobjects and syscolumns but the information_schema versions of each.

Comment: The alter table in case of a primary key is dangling as well.

Answer (score 38):

Here's the script that I came up with. It handles Identity columns, default values, and primary keys. It does not handle foreign keys, indexes, triggers, or any other clever stuff. It works on SQLServer 2000, 2005 and 2008.

```
declare @schema varchar(100), @table varchar(100)
set @schema = 'dbo' -- set schema name here
set @table = 'MyTable' -- set table name here
declare @sql table(s varchar(1000), id int identity)

-- create statement
insert into  @sql(s) values ('create table [' + @table + '] (')

-- column list
insert into @sql(s)
select 
    '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
    data_type + coalesce('('+cast(character_maximum_length as varchar)+')','') + ' ' +
    case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=@table
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
    ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(@table) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(@table) as varchar) + ')'
    else ''
    end + ' ' +
    ( case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
    coalesce('DEFAULT '+COLUMN_DEFAULT,'') + ','

 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = @table AND table_schema = @schema
 order by ordinal_position

-- primary key
declare @pkname varchar(100)
select @pkname = constraint_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where table_name = @table and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'

if ( @pkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values('  PRIMARY KEY (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '   ['+COLUMN_NAME+'],' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        where constraint_name = @pkname
        order by ordinal_position
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  )')
end
else begin
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
end

-- closing bracket
insert into @sql(s) values( ')' )

-- result!
select s from @sql order by id
```

Comment: Lots of systems won't be able to run this due to the dynamic sql. On your local box probably not a problem, but just wanted to point that out.

Comment: What dynamic sql? This script generates sql - it doesn't execute it.

Comment: Would love to see this broken down into steps so it can be performed with a series of queries that can be written in C++

Comment: You're missing support for the Schema if it is not 'dbo'. Also, if a database has the same table name with different schema, problems will arise. I got out of it what I needed though, thanks.

Comment: @TT. are you sure? `select cast(123456 as varchar)` returns `123456` for me.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ah yes, sorry about that. In a CAST statement the default is 30 when not specifying the length. In data definition or variable declarations it's 1. I thought it was always 1. Oops =). (Removing invalid comment).

Comment: this is not one line statement

Comment: @ob213 so? who said it should be?

Answer (score 14):

There is a Powershell script buried in the [msdb](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/69784251-ff9a-4eb2-96a2-9eacb292bd4a) forums that will script all the tables and related objects:

```
# Script all tables in a database
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") 
    | out-null

$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') '<Servername>'
$db = $s.Databases['<Database>']

$scrp = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($s)
$scrp.Options.AppendToFile = $True
$scrp.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
$scrp.Options.DriAll = $True
$scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = $False
$scrp.Options.IncludeHeaders = $False
$scrp.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
$scrp.Options.Indexes = $True
$scrp.Options.WithDependencies = $True
$scrp.Options.FileName = 'C:\Temp\<Database>.SQL'

foreach($item in $db.Tables) { $tablearray+=@($item) }
$scrp.Script($tablearray)

Write-Host "Scripting complete"
```

Comment: SMO is great when you have permissions to use it.  I've found many systems where that wasn't the case though, so a pure INFORMATION_SCHEMA approach has some advantages.

Answer (score 12):

**Support for schemas:**

This is an updated version that amends the great answer from David, et al. Added is support for named schemas. It should be noted this may break if there's actually tables of the same name present within various schemas. Another improvement is the use of the official [QuoteName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function.

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_CATALOG,
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    'create table '+QuoteName(t.TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.' + QuoteName(so.name) + ' (' + LEFT(o.List, Len(o.List)-1) + ');  ' 
        + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' 
          ELSE 
            'ALTER TABLE ' + QuoteName(t.TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.' + QuoteName(so.name) 
            + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ');  ' 
          END as 'SQL_CREATE_TABLE'
FROM sysobjects so

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
          '  ['+column_name+'] ' 
          +  data_type 
          + case data_type
                when 'sql_variant' then ''
                when 'text' then ''
                when 'ntext' then ''
                when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
              else 
              coalesce(
                '('+ case when character_maximum_length = -1 
                    then 'MAX' 
                    else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end 
                + ')','') 
            end 
        + ' ' 
        + case when exists ( 
            SELECT id 
            FROM syscolumns
            WHERE 
                object_name(id) = so.name
                and name = column_name
                and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
          ) then
            'IDENTITY(' + 
            cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
            cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
          else ''
          end 
        + ' ' 
        + (case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end) 
        + 'NULL ' 
        + case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
          ELSE '' 
          END 
        + ','  -- can't have a field name or we'll end up with XML

    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = so.name
    ORDER BY ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')
) o (list)

LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tc on  
    tc.Table_name = so.Name
    AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'

LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables t on  
    t.Table_name = so.Name

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT QuoteName(Column_Name) + ', '
    FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
    WHERE kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR XML PATH('')
) j (list)

WHERE
    xtype = 'U'
    AND name NOT IN ('dtproperties')
    -- AND so.name = 'ASPStateTempSessions'
;
```

..

**For use in Management Studio:**

One detractor to the sql code above is if you test it using SSMS, long statements aren't easy to read. So, as per [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques), here's another version that's somewhat modified to be easier on the eyes after clicking the link of a cell in the grid. The results are more readily identifiable as nicely formatted CREATE TABLE statements for each table in the db.

```
-- settings
DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2)
SET @CRLF = Nchar(13) + NChar(10)
DECLARE @PLACEHOLDER NCHAR(3)
SET @PLACEHOLDER = '{:}'

-- the main query
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_CATALOG,
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    CAST(
        REPLACE(
            'create table ' + QuoteName(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QuoteName(so.name) + ' (' + @CRLF 
            + LEFT(o.List, Len(o.List) - (LEN(@PLACEHOLDER)+2)) + @CRLF + ');' + @CRLF
            + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' 
              ELSE
                'ALTER TABLE ' + QuoteName(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QuoteName(so.Name) 
                + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List) - 1) + ');' + @CRLF
              END,
            @PLACEHOLDER,
            @CRLF
        )
    AS XML) as 'SQL_CREATE_TABLE'
FROM sysobjects so

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
          '   '
          + '['+column_name+'] ' 
          +  data_type 
          + case data_type
                when 'sql_variant' then ''
                when 'text' then ''
                when 'ntext' then ''
                when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
              else 
              coalesce(
                '('+ case when character_maximum_length = -1 
                    then 'MAX' 
                    else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end 
                + ')','') 
            end 
        + ' ' 
        + case when exists ( 
            SELECT id 
            FROM syscolumns
            WHERE 
                object_name(id) = so.name
                and name = column_name
                and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
          ) then
            'IDENTITY(' + 
            cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
            cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
          else ''
          end 
        + ' ' 
        + (case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end) 
        + 'NULL ' 
        + case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
          ELSE '' 
          END 
        + ', ' 
        + @PLACEHOLDER  -- note, can't have a field name or we'll end up with XML

    FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name
    ORDER BY ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')
) o (list)

LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tc on  
    tc.Table_name = so.Name
    AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'

LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables t on  
    t.Table_name = so.Name

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT QUOTENAME(Column_Name) + ', '
    FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
    WHERE kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR XML PATH('')
) j (list)

WHERE
    xtype = 'U'
    AND name NOT IN ('dtproperties')
    -- AND so.name = 'ASPStateTempSessions'
;
```

Not to belabor the point, but here's the functionally equivalent example outputs for comparison:

```
-- 1 (scripting version)
create table [dbo].[ASPStateTempApplications] (  [AppId] int  NOT NULL ,  [AppName] char(280)  NOT NULL );  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ASPStateTempApplications] ADD CONSTRAINT PK__ASPState__8E2CF7F908EA5793 PRIMARY KEY  ([AppId]);  

-- 2 (SSMS version)
create table [dbo].[ASPStateTempSessions] (
   [SessionId] nvarchar(88)  NOT NULL , 
   [Created] datetime  NOT NULL DEFAULT (getutcdate()), 
   [Expires] datetime  NOT NULL , 
   [LockDate] datetime  NOT NULL , 
   [LockDateLocal] datetime  NOT NULL , 
   [LockCookie] int  NOT NULL , 
   [Timeout] int  NOT NULL , 
   [Locked] bit  NOT NULL , 
   [SessionItemShort] varbinary(7000)  NULL , 
   [SessionItemLong] image(2147483647)  NULL , 
   [Flags] int  NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ASPStateTempSessions] ADD CONSTRAINT PK__ASPState__C9F4929003317E3D PRIMARY KEY ([SessionId]);
```

..

**Detracting factors:**

It should be noted that I remain relatively unhappy with this due to the lack of support for indeces other than a primary key. It remains suitable for use as a mechanism for simple data export or replication.

Comment: This actually works for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, super useful!

Answer (score 8):

If the application you are generating the scripts from is a .NET application, you may want to look into using SMO (Sql Management Objects).  Reference this [SQL Team link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated) on how to use SMO to script objects.

Answer (score 8):

One more variant with foreign keys support and in one statement:

```
 SELECT
        obj.name
        ,'CREATE TABLE [' + obj.name + '] (' + LEFT(cols.list, LEN(cols.list) - 1 ) + ')'
        + ISNULL(' ' + refs.list, '')
    FROM sysobjects obj
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            CHAR(10)
            + ' [' + column_name + '] '
            + data_type
            + CASE data_type
                WHEN 'sql_variant' THEN ''
                WHEN 'text' THEN ''
                WHEN 'ntext' THEN ''
                WHEN 'xml' THEN ''
                WHEN 'decimal' THEN '(' + CAST(numeric_precision as VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(numeric_scale as VARCHAR) + ')'
                ELSE COALESCE('(' + CASE WHEN character_maximum_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(character_maximum_length as VARCHAR) END + ')', '')
            END
            + ' '
            + case when exists ( -- Identity skip
            select id from syscolumns
            where object_name(id) = obj.name
            and name = column_name
            and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
            ) then
            'IDENTITY(' + 
            cast(ident_seed(obj.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
            cast(ident_incr(obj.name) as varchar) + ')'
            else ''
            end + ' '
            + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'No' THEN 'NOT ' ELSE '' END
            + 'NULL'
            + CASE WHEN information_schema.columns.column_default IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT ' + information_schema.columns.column_default ELSE '' END
            + ','
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = obj.name
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) cols (list)
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT
            CHAR(10) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + obj.name + '_noident_temp ADD ' + LEFT(alt, LEN(alt)-1)
        FROM(
            SELECT
                CHAR(10)
                + ' CONSTRAINT ' + tc.constraint_name
                + ' ' + tc.constraint_type + ' (' + LEFT(c.list, LEN(c.list)-1) + ')'
                + COALESCE(CHAR(10) + r.list, ', ')
            FROM
                information_schema.table_constraints tc
                CROSS APPLY(
                    SELECT
                        '[' + kcu.column_name + '], '
                    FROM
                        information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
                    WHERE
                        kcu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
                    ORDER BY
                        kcu.ordinal_position
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) c (list)
                OUTER APPLY(
                    -- // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907879/sql-server-howto-get-foreign-key-reference-from-information-schema
                    SELECT
                        '  REFERENCES [' + kcu1.constraint_schema + '].' + '[' + kcu2.table_name + ']' + '(' + kcu2.column_name + '), '
                    FROM information_schema.referential_constraints as rc
                        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage as kcu1 ON (kcu1.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog AND kcu1.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema AND kcu1.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name)
                        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage as kcu2 ON (kcu2.constraint_catalog = rc.unique_constraint_catalog AND kcu2.constraint_schema = rc.unique_constraint_schema AND kcu2.constraint_name = rc.unique_constraint_name AND kcu2.ordinal_position = KCU1.ordinal_position)
                    WHERE
                        kcu1.constraint_catalog = tc.constraint_catalog AND kcu1.constraint_schema = tc.constraint_schema AND kcu1.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
                ) r (list)
            WHERE tc.table_name = obj.name
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) a (alt)
    ) refs (list)
    WHERE
        xtype = 'U'
    AND name NOT IN ('dtproperties')
    AND obj.name = 'your_table_name'
```

You could try in is sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3b66/3/0

Comment: I like this one for its single statement solution and it supports foreign keys. The first 2 instances of `@tableName` can be replaced with `so.name` making it easier to generate create table scripts for multiple tables at once.

Comment: Also when there's not a single constraint, like a primary key, the query would be `NULL`. To solve this `' ' + j.list` should be `ISNULL(' ' + j.list, '')`. I took the liberty to adjust the code for the use cases described in both of my comments

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek suggestions looks reasonable. But I do not understand last case. When j.list will be null? May be example?

Comment: j.list will be null when you run the script for a table that has no primary key.

Comment: I have made changes by your first comment, thank you. But I could not reproduce null. Please look at fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/969a3/5/0

Comment: Try it with the table district in your fiddle. You'll see a null. Also the last column has a trailing comma that should not be there. Still like your answer though :)

Comment: Ah, you speak about tables does not have eny keys! Thanks, it fixed too. Last comma is not issue because it correct SQL, but it (among with more readable names of subqueries) aslo fixed for estetic.

Answer (score 7):

I modified the accepted answer and now it can get the command including primary key and foreign key in a certain schema.

```
declare @table varchar(100)
declare @schema varchar(100)
set @table = 'Persons' -- set table name here
set @schema = 'OT' -- set SCHEMA name here
declare @sql table(s varchar(1000), id int identity)

-- create statement
insert into  @sql(s) values ('create table ' + @table + ' (')

-- column list
insert into @sql(s)
select 
    '  '+column_name+' ' + 
    data_type + coalesce('('+cast(character_maximum_length as varchar)+')','') + ' ' +
    case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=@table
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
    ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(@table) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(@table) as varchar) + ')'
    else ''
    end + ' ' +
    ( case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
    coalesce('DEFAULT '+COLUMN_DEFAULT,'') + ','

 from information_schema.columns where table_name = @table and table_schema = @schema
 order by ordinal_position

-- primary key
declare @pkname varchar(100)
select @pkname = constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = @table and constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'

if ( @pkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values('  PRIMARY KEY (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '   '+COLUMN_NAME+',' from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where constraint_name = @pkname
        order by ordinal_position
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  )')
end
else begin
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
end


-- foreign key
declare @fkname varchar(100)
select @fkname = constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = @table and constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'

if ( @fkname is not null ) begin
    insert into @sql(s) values(',')
    insert into @sql(s) values('  FOREIGN KEY (')
    insert into @sql(s)
        select '   '+COLUMN_NAME+',' from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where constraint_name = @fkname
        order by ordinal_position
    -- remove trailing comma
    update @sql set s=left(s,len(s)-1) where id=@@identity
    insert into @sql(s) values ('  ) REFERENCES ')
    insert into @sql(s) 
        SELECT  
            OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id)
        FROM 
            sys.foreign_keys fk
        INNER JOIN 
            sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
        INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
        INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
        where fk.name = @fkname
    insert into @sql(s) 
        SELECT  
            '('+c2.name+')'
        FROM 
            sys.foreign_keys fk
        INNER JOIN 
            sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
        INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
        INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
        where fk.name = @fkname
end

-- closing bracket
insert into @sql(s) values( ')' )

-- result!
select s from @sql order by id
```

Comment: Might be nice to republish this (edit) into the accepted answer. That seems adequately in the spirit of SO. Schemas and newlines from my answer would be nice as well for a comprehensive one-stop human-friendly solution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to improve the answer by supporting partitioned tables:

find partition scheme and partition key using below scritps:

```
declare @partition_scheme varchar(100) = (
select distinct ps.Name AS PartitionScheme
from sys.indexes i  
join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id=p.object_id AND i.index_id=p.index_id  
join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id  
where i.object_id = object_id('your table name')
)
print @partition_scheme

declare @partition_column varchar(100) = (
select c.name 
from  sys.tables          t
join  sys.indexes         i 
      on(i.object_id = t.object_id 
  and i.index_id < 2)
join  sys.index_columns  ic 
  on(ic.partition_ordinal > 0 
  and ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = t.object_id)
join  sys.columns         c 
  on(c.object_id = ic.object_id 
  and c.column_id = ic.column_id)
where t.object_id  = object_id('your table name')
)
print @partition_column
```

then change the generation query by adding below line at the right place:

```
+ IIF(@partition_scheme is null, '', 'ON [' + @partition_scheme + ']([' + @partition_column + '])')
```

Answer (score 4):

Credit due to @Blorgbeard for sharing his script.  I'll certainly bookmark it in case I need it.

Yes, you can "right click" on the table and script the `CREATE TABLE` script, but:

- The a script will contain **loads** of cruft (interested in the extended properties anyone?)
- If you have 200+ tables in your schema, it's going to take you half a day to script the lot by hand.

With this script converted into a stored procedure, and combined with a wrapper script you would have a nice automated way to dump your table design into source control etc.

The rest of your DB code (SP's, FK indexes, Triggers etc) would be under source control anyway ;)

Comment: I think a dbproject can import the schema directly from the server, so you dont need to checkin the create table statements, and in SSMS you can script out multiple tables, either by using "Object Explorer Details" or right clicking on the database in object explorer and selecting Tasks->Generate scripts

Answer (score 4):

Something I've noticed - in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH gives a size of 2147483647 (2^31-1) for field types such as image and text. ntext is 2^30-1 (being double-byte unicode and all).

This size is included in the output from this query, but it is invalid for these data types in a CREATE statement (they should not have a maximum size value at all). So unless the results from this are manually corrected, the CREATE script won't work given these data types.

I imagine it's possible to fix the script to account for this, but that's beyond my SQL capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

-- or you could create a stored procedure ... first with Id creation

```
USE [db]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procUtils_InsertGeneratorWithId]    Script Date: 06/13/2009 22:18:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


create PROC [dbo].[procUtils_InsertGeneratorWithId]    
(    
@domain_user varchar(50),    
@tableName varchar(100)    
)     


as    

--Declare a cursor to retrieve column specific information for the specified table    
DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR     
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @tableName    
OPEN cursCol    
DECLARE @string nvarchar(3000) --for storing the first half of INSERT statement    
DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(3000) --for storing the data (VALUES) related statement    
DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(1000) --data types returned for respective columns    
DECLARE @IDENTITY_STRING nvarchar ( 100 )    
SET @IDENTITY_STRING = ' '     
select  @IDENTITY_STRING    
SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('    
SET @stringData=''    

DECLARE @colName nvarchar(50)    

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType    

IF @@fetch_status<>0    
 begin    
 print 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'    
 close curscol    
 deallocate curscol    
 return    
END    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0    
BEGIN    
IF @dataType in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')    
BEGIN    
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull('+@colName+','''')+'''''',''+'    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+'+@colName+'+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'    
END    
ELSE    
if @dataType in ('text','ntext') --if the datatype is text or something else     
BEGIN    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(2000)),'''')+'''''',''+'    
END    
ELSE    
IF @dataType = 'money' --because money doesn't get converted from varchar implicitly    
BEGIN    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(money,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'    
END    
ELSE     
IF @dataType='datetime'    
BEGIN    
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+''''''),''+'    
 --SELECT 'INSERT Authorizations(StatusDate) VALUES('+'convert(datetime,'+isnull(''''+convert(varchar(200),StatusDate,121)+'''','NULL')+',121),)' FROM Authorizations    
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(money,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,'+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+',121)+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',121),''+'    
  --                             'convert(datetime,'+isnull(''''+convert(varchar(200),StatusDate,121)+'''','NULL')+',121),)' FROM Authorizations    
END    
ELSE     
IF @dataType='image'     
BEGIN    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast(convert(varbinary,'+@colName+') as varchar(6)),''0'')+'''''',''+'    
END    
ELSE --presuming the data type is int,bit,numeric,decimal     
BEGIN    
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+'''''',''+'    
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,'+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+',121)+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',121),''+'    
 SET @stringData=@stringData+''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+')+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'    
END    

SET @string=@string+@colName+','    

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType    
END    
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)    

SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@string,0,len(@string)) + ') VALUES(''+ ' + substring(@stringData,0,len(@stringData)-2)+'''+'')'' FROM '+@tableName    
exec sp_executesql @query    
--select @query    

CLOSE cursCol    
DEALLOCATE cursCol    


  /*
USAGE

*/

GO
```

-- and second without iD INSERTION

```
USE [db]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procUtils_InsertGenerator]    Script Date: 06/13/2009 22:20:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[procUtils_InsertGenerator]        
(        
@domain_user varchar(50),        
@tableName varchar(100)        
)         


as        

--Declare a cursor to retrieve column specific information for the specified table        
DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR         


-- SELECT column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @tableName        
/* NEW     
SELECT c.name , sc.data_type  FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep                   
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON ep.major_id = t.object_id                   
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id                   
= c.column_id                   
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sc ON t.name = sc.table_name and                   
c.name = sc.column_name                   
WHERE t.name = @tableName and c.is_identity=0      
  */      

select object_name(c.object_id) "TABLE_NAME", c.name "COLUMN_NAME", s.name "DATA_TYPE"      
  from sys.columns c          
  join sys.systypes s on (s.xtype = c.system_type_id)          
  where object_name(c.object_id) in (select name from sys.tables where name not like 'sysdiagrams')          
   AND object_name(c.object_id) in (select name from sys.tables where [name]=@tableName  ) and c.is_identity=0 and s.name not like 'sysname'  




OPEN cursCol        
DECLARE @string nvarchar(3000) --for storing the first half of INSERT statement        
DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(3000) --for storing the data (VALUES) related statement        
DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(1000) --data types returned for respective columns        
DECLARE @IDENTITY_STRING nvarchar ( 100 )        
SET @IDENTITY_STRING = ' '         
select  @IDENTITY_STRING        
SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('        
SET @stringData=''        

DECLARE @colName nvarchar(50)        

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @tableName , @colName,@dataType        

IF @@fetch_status<>0        
 begin        
 print 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'        
 close curscol        
 deallocate curscol        
 return        
END        

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0        
BEGIN        
IF @dataType in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')        
BEGIN        
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull('+@colName+','''')+'''''',''+'        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+'+@colName+'+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'        
END        
ELSE        
if @dataType in ('text','ntext') --if the datatype is text or something else         
BEGIN        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(2000)),'''')+'''''',''+'        
END        
ELSE        
IF @dataType = 'money' --because money doesn't get converted from varchar implicitly        
BEGIN        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(money,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'        
END        
ELSE         
IF @dataType='datetime'        
BEGIN        
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+''''''),''+'        
 --SELECT 'INSERT Authorizations(StatusDate) VALUES('+'convert(datetime,'+isnull(''''+convert(varchar(200),StatusDate,121)+'''','NULL')+',121),)' FROM Authorizations        
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(money,''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,'+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+',121)+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',121),''+'        
  --                             'convert(datetime,'+isnull(''''+convert(varchar(200),StatusDate,121)+'''','NULL')+',121),)' FROM Authorizations        
END        
ELSE         
IF @dataType='image'         
BEGIN        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast(convert(varbinary,'+@colName+') as varchar(6)),''0'')+'''''',''+'        
END        
ELSE --presuming the data type is int,bit,numeric,decimal         
BEGIN        
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+'''''',''+'        
 --SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,'+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+',121)+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',121),''+'        
 SET @stringData=@stringData+''''+'''+isnull('''''+'''''+convert(varchar(200),'+@colName+')+'''''+''''',''NULL'')+'',''+'        
END        

SET @string=@string+@colName+','        

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @tableName , @colName,@dataType        
END        
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)        

SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@string,0,len(@string)) + ') VALUES(''+ ' + substring(@stringData,0,len(@stringData)-2)+'''+'')'' FROM '+@tableName        
exec sp_executesql @query        
--select @query       

CLOSE cursCol        
DEALLOCATE cursCol        


  /*      

use poc     
go    

DECLARE @RC int      
DECLARE @domain_user varchar(50)      
DECLARE @tableName varchar(100)      

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.      
set @domain_user='yorgeorg'      
set @tableName = 'tbGui_WizardTabButtonAreas'      

EXECUTE @RC = [POC].[dbo].[procUtils_InsertGenerator]       
   @domain_user      
  ,@tableName      

*/
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

[Show create table in classic asp](http://www.varuste.net/show_create_table.html) (handles constraints, primary keys, copying the table structure and/or data ...)

> Sql server Show create table
>   Mysql-style "Show create table" and "show create database" commands from Microsoft sql server.
>   The script is written is Microsoft asp-language and is quite easy to port to another language.*

Answer (score 2):

I include definitions for computed columns

```
    select 'CREATE TABLE [' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'ALTER TABLE ' + so.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')' END, name
from    sysobjects so
cross apply
    (SELECT

case when comps.definition is not null then '  ['+column_name+'] AS ' + comps.definition 
else
        '  ['+column_name+'] ' + data_type + 
        case
        when data_type like '%text' or data_type in ('image', 'sql_variant' ,'xml')
            then ''
        when data_type in ('float')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(numeric_precision, 18) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when data_type in ('datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'time')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(datetime_precision, 7) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when data_type in ('decimal', 'numeric')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(numeric_precision, 18) as varchar(11)) + ',' + cast(coalesce(numeric_scale, 0) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when (data_type like '%binary' or data_type like '%char') and character_maximum_length = -1
            then '(max)'
        when character_maximum_length is not null
            then '(' + cast(character_maximum_length as varchar(11)) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
        case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=so.name
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
        ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
         (case when information_schema.columns.IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
          case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT ELSE '' END 
end + ', ' 

     from information_schema.columns 
     left join sys.computed_columns comps 
     on OBJECT_ID(information_schema.columns.TABLE_NAME)=comps.object_id and information_schema.columns.COLUMN_NAME=comps.name

     where table_name = so.name
     order by ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)
left join
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
on  tc.Table_name       = so.Name
AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
cross apply
    (select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
     FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     WHERE  kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
     ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION
     FOR XML PATH('')) j (list)
where   xtype = 'U'
AND name    NOT IN ('dtproperties')
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise that it's been a very long time but thought I'd add anyway. If you just want the table, and not the create table statement you could use

```
select into x from db.schema.y where 1=0
```

to copy the table to a new DB

Comment: One note on this method is that it won't copy extended information like constraints or default values but it's still a simple solution for a straight table copy.

Answer (score 1):

A query based on Hubbitus answer.

- includes schema names
- fixes foreign keys with more than one field
- includes CASCADE UPDATE & DELETE
- includes a conditioned DROP TABLE

```
SELECT 
  Schema_Name = SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid)
, Table_Name = name
, Drop_Table = 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid) + '''  AND  TABLE_NAME = ''' + obj.name + '''))
DROP TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid) + '].[' + obj.name + '] '
, Create_Table ='
CREATE TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid) + '].[' + obj.name + '] (' + LEFT(cols.list, LEN(cols.list) - 1 ) + ')' + ISNULL(' ' + refs.list, '')
    FROM sysobjects obj
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            CHAR(10)
            + ' [' + column_name + '] '
            + data_type
            + CASE data_type
                WHEN 'sql_variant' THEN ''
                WHEN 'text' THEN ''
                WHEN 'ntext' THEN ''
                WHEN 'xml' THEN ''
                WHEN 'decimal' THEN '(' + CAST(numeric_precision as VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(numeric_scale as VARCHAR) + ')'
                ELSE COALESCE('(' + CASE WHEN character_maximum_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(character_maximum_length as VARCHAR) END + ')', '')
            END
            + ' '
            + case when exists ( -- Identity skip
                                select id from syscolumns
                                where id = obj.id
                                and name = column_name
                                and columnproperty(id, name, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
                                ) then
                        'IDENTITY(' + 
                            cast(ident_seed(obj.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
                            cast(ident_incr(obj.name) as varchar) + ')'
            else ''
            end + ' '
            + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'No' THEN 'NOT ' ELSE '' END
            + 'NULL'
            + CASE WHEN IC.column_default IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT ' + IC.column_default ELSE '' END
            + ','
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC
        WHERE IC.table_name   = obj.name
          AND IC.TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid)
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) cols (list)
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT
            CHAR(10) + 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.uid) + '].[' + obj.name + '] ADD ' + LEFT(alt, LEN(alt)-1)
        FROM(
            SELECT
                CHAR(10)
                + ' CONSTRAINT ' + tc.constraint_name
                + ' ' + tc.constraint_type + ' (' + LEFT(c.list, LEN(c.list)-1) + ')'
                + COALESCE(CHAR(10) + r.list, ', ')
            FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
                CROSS APPLY(
                    SELECT   '[' + kcu.column_name + '], '
                    FROM     information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
                    WHERE    kcu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
                    ORDER BY kcu.ordinal_position
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) c (list)
                OUTER APPLY(
                    -- // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907879/sql-server-howto-get-foreign-key-reference-from-information-schema
                    SELECT LEFT(f.list, LEN(f.list)-1) + ')' + IIF(rc.DELETE_RULE = 'NO ACTION', '', ' ON DELETE ' + rc.DELETE_RULE) + IIF(rc.UPDATE_RULE = 'NO ACTION', '', ' ON UPDATE ' + rc.UPDATE_RULE) + ', '
                    FROM information_schema.referential_constraints rc
                    CROSS APPLY(
                        SELECT IIF(kcu.ordinal_position = 1, ' REFERENCES [' + kcu.table_schema + '].[' + kcu.table_name + '] (', '') 
                                + '[' + kcu.column_name + '], '
                        FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
                        WHERE kcu.constraint_catalog = rc.unique_constraint_catalog AND kcu.constraint_schema = rc.unique_constraint_schema AND kcu.constraint_name = rc.unique_constraint_name
                        ORDER BY kcu.ordinal_position
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    ) f (list)
                    WHERE rc.constraint_catalog = tc.constraint_catalog 
                      AND rc.constraint_schema  = tc.constraint_schema 
                      AND rc.constraint_name    = tc.constraint_name
                ) r (list)
            WHERE tc.table_name = obj.name
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) a (alt)
    ) refs (list)
    WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

To combine drop table (if exists) with create use like this:

```
SELECT Drop_Table + CHAR(10) + Create_Table FROM SysCreateTables
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using management studio and have the query analyzer window open you can drag the table name to the query analyzer window and ... bingo! you get the table script. 
I've not tried this in SQL2008

Comment: That's a neat shortcut, but again: I needed to do it programmatically.