# Programmatically retrieve database table creation script in .NET

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sqldmo

I need to be able to retrieve a CREATE TABLE script to recreate a specific table in a SQL Server (2000) database, programmatically (I'm using C#). Obviously you can do this with Enterprise Manager but I would like to automate it.

I've been playing around with SQLDMO which offers a Backup command, but I'm not sure if this will give a SQL CREATE TABLE script and seems to require the creation of a SQL Service device, and I would prefer to avoid modifying the database.

Comment: Here is another method http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/08/27/generate-sql-script.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [my solution](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-mssql-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table). It's a sql script which uses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to get the necessary information. It's basic, but might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMO to generate the scripts. For more info see: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated