# sql 2005 force table rename that has dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you force a rename???

Rename failed for Table 'dbo.x.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.2531.0+((Katmai_PCU_Main).090329-1045+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Rename+Table&LinkId=20476

---

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Object '[dbo].[x]' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15336)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4035&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15336&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Find the "enforced dependencies", then remove or disable them.

By "enforced dependencies", it means Schema binding, so you'll have to look specifically for that.

Here's a query to look for schema binding references to your object:

```
select o.name as ObjName, r.name as ReferencedObj
from sys.sql_dependencies d
join sys.objects o on o.object_id=d.object_id
join sys.objects r on r.object_id=d.referenced_major_id
where d.class=1
AND r.name = @YourObjectName
```

As I noted in the comments, there is *no* *way* to FORCE-ibly override Schema Binding.  When you use Schema Binding, you are explicitly saying "Do *not* let me or anyone else override this."  The only way around Schema Binding is to undo it, and that's intentional.

Comment: For me it shown the same table, if this occurs it can be a computed column

Comment: A simplified query is as below:  

    `select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as ObjName, OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) as ReferencedObj   
    from sys.sql_dependencies  

    where class = 1 and OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) = @YourObjectName`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue , my problem was that i has a COMPUTED FIELD using the column i was trying to rename.

by running the query from the selected answer i was able to tell that had enforced dependencies, but i was not able to see exactly what was the problem

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/*  
    Example 1: Rename a table dbo.MyTable -> dbo.YourTable
    EXEC dbo.USP_DROP_ENFORCED_DEPENDENCIES @SchemaName=N'dbo', @EntityName=N'MyTable', @Debug=1;
    EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.MyTable', N'YourTable', N'OBJECT'

    Example 2: Rename a column dbo.MyTable.MyColumn -> dbo.MyTable.YourColumn
    EXEC dbo.USP_DROP_ENFORCED_DEPENDENCIES @SchemaName=N'dbo', @EntityName=N'MyTable', @ColumnName=N'MyColumn' @Debug=1;
    EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.MyTable.MyColumn', N'YourColumn', N'COLUMN'

*/
CREATE Procedure dbo.USP_DROP_ENFORCED_DEPENDENCIES
(
    @SchemaName sysname = 'dbo',
    @EntityName sysname,
    @ColumnName sysname = NULL,
    @Debug      bit = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;

    DECLARE @ReferencingEntitySchema sysname, @ReferencingEntityName sysname, @ReferencingEntityType nvarchar(8), @SqlScript nvarchar(512);

    DECLARE ReferencingEntitiesCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR 
        SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(dep.referencing_id) AS [schema]
              ,referencing_entity.name
              ,CASE referencing_entity.type 
                   WHEN 'V' THEN N'VIEW'
                   ELSE /*IF, FN, TF*/ N'FUNCTION'
               END as [type]
        FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS dep
            INNER JOIN sys.objects AS referencing_entity 
                ON dep.referencing_id = referencing_entity.object_id
        WHERE dep.referenced_entity_name = @EntityName 
              AND dep.referenced_schema_name = @SchemaName 
              AND is_schema_bound_reference = 1
              AND ((@ColumnName IS NULL AND dep.referenced_minor_id = 0) OR COL_NAME(dep.referenced_id, dep.referenced_minor_id) = @ColumnName)
    OPEN ReferencingEntitiesCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM ReferencingEntitiesCursor
    INTO @ReferencingEntitySchema, @ReferencingEntityName, @ReferencingEntityType;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.USP_DROP_ENFORCED_DEPENDENCIES @SchemaName=@ReferencingEntitySchema, @EntityName=@ReferencingEntityName, @Debug=@Debug;
        --The goal is to produce the following script:
        /*
        DROP FUNCTION dbo.UFN_SOME_FUNCTION;
        OR
        DROP VIEW dbo.UFN_SOME_VIEW;
        */
        SET @SqlScript = N'DROP ' + @ReferencingEntityType + N' ' + @ReferencingEntitySchema + '.' + @ReferencingEntityName;
        IF(@Debug = 1)
            RAISERROR (@SqlScript, 0/*severity*/, 0/*state*/) WITH NOWAIT;
        EXEC (@SqlScript);

        FETCH NEXT FROM ReferencingEntitiesCursor
        INTO @ReferencingEntitySchema, @ReferencingEntityName, @ReferencingEntityType;
    END

    CLOSE ReferencingEntitiesCursor;
    DEALLOCATE ReferencingEntitiesCursor;       
END
GO
```

Comment: I have ***check constraint*** for ***TABLE***, not for **COLUMN**. Eg: `CREATE TABLE [zzzz](
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [NumTotal] [int] NOT NULL,
 [NumUsadas] [int] default 0 NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_zzzz CHECK (NumUsadas <= NumTotal AND NumTotal >= 0),
 PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)`

Answer (score 3):

In the SQL Server Object Browser, right-click on the table with the issue and select `View Dependencies`. Next in the view listed, Right-click (view) and select SCRIPT to CREATE VIEW in New SQL Query Editor window, then remove `WITH SCHEMABINDING` from the CREATE VIEW t-sql script and run the revised CREATE VIEW t-sql. This unlinks the schema dependency from the table. I was able to recreate the table at this point (DROP, RENAME, etc).

> Note:
>
> Schema binding can occur on functions and other objects in your db.
>   Use of `View Dependencies` on the object throwing the error is essential
>   to fix the issue.
>
> BTW:
>
> I originally added schema binding to enable view indexing. Keeping a
>   good index on the underlying table(s) may mitigate the performance hit
>   of not having one on the view.

1. [View Dependencies](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1294/listing-sql-server-object-dependencies/)
2. [More on Schema Binding](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this. I dropped constraints on this DB object, renamed the DB object then recreated these constraints. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this script to get dependent view with schemabingings:

```
select distinct o.name, o.type from sys.sql_expression_dependencies dep inner join sys.objects o on dep.referencing_id=o.object_id where referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(<your dependency owner object>) and o.type = 'V'
```