# Change table name with dependencies in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change the table name in SQL server management studio 2008
Using the following query.

```
Exec sp_rename 'table', 'table2'.
```

After executing the query it says,

> The object 'table' can't be renamed because the object participates in
>   enforced dependencies.

I have checked the table, it has around 160 objects depending on it.

1. How do I rename the table?
2. Can I rename all the dependencies along with the table?

Comment: 1 - `sp_rename`. 2 - no. only manually in all source objects

Comment: Renaming the dependencies isn't going to do you any good. This means that you have schema bound objects referencing your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql 2005 force table rename that has dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540988/sql-2005-force-table-rename-that-has-dependencies)

Comment: Always have a script to create the complete database. When you need to make any changes, simply adjust the script, drop the complete database and re-create it.

Comment: @jarlh are you serious?

Comment: use SSDT and create a database project. then it's as simple as a right click->rename, and it will change in all depedencies. then you can script a change script.

Comment: @SeanLange, very convenient when developing, as you may re-arrange tables over and over again, and with such scripts you can easily go back (and forth). In production however, I wouldn't dare to rename a table.