# PostgreSQL command to show entity relations

Tags: postgresql, psql

At the start I want to point that I am not and I never was database administrator. I have got experience and knowledge about `PL/SQL` and `SQL` but so far each database i get touch with was max 50 tables and looking for relation between entities wasn't that hard even if I made it manually.
 Problem comes now, when I have got `database` which have over 300 tables finding relation between entities is not so easy. 
 Let imagine table:

```
table person (
id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name varchar(45)
)
```

and automaticly i have sequence:

```
person_id_seq
```

Can you please tell me if there is any command which return me tables which are using `person_id_seq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

klin's answer - use `pg_depend` is entirely sensible, and a sane way to do this.

I strongly recommend that you try a tool like [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) to produce database maps and visualisations. It will help a lot, and give you a chance to get an overview of the relationships, not just explore them piece by piece.

If you need to make your query portable then you can use the `information_schema` instead of PostgreSQL-specific catalog tables. [This query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907999/398670) produces a list of foreign key relationships portably - the query was written for MS SQL Server, but is fine on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 6):

See [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html).

```
select *, pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid)
from pg_depend 
where refobjid = 'person_id_seq'::regclass
```

Comment: is it possible for me to not have `pg_describe_object` ? i got syntax error there..

Comment: Function pg_describe_object() was introduced in Postgres 9.1. 
It is very informative and makes browsing on pg_depend much easier. 
My answer was somehow formal. In context of your general problem with finding complex dependencies I think you should follow Craig's advise.