# Get list of referencing tables in SQL Server using C#, SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

Consider there are three tables in database, say person, student, teacher.

```
person (person_id, name, person specific columns...),
student(student_id, foreignKey(person_id), student specific columns... )
teacher(teacher_id, foreignKey(person_id), teacher specific columns... )
```

using SMO, I am able navigate to person table from both student and teacher table.

```
   ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(conn);
   Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
   Database db = server.Databases[databaseName];
   Table tbl = db.Tables("student");

   foreach (ForeignKey fk in tbl.ForeignKeys)
   { 
       //do something
   }
```

I want to get the reverse, like what are all the tables (keys) referring Person table's person_id as foreign key, using C# SMO.

P.S: please advice or suggest using C#, but not using DMV.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like this is duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907879/sql-server-howto-get-foreign-key-reference-from-information-schema>. You don't need SMO for this. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. All information on existing objects is stored in tables and all you need is to know how to select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use SMO, you can use the [DependencyWalker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.dependencywalker.aspx) object for this.

**Example:**

```
var tbl = db.Tables["person"];
var dw = new DependencyWalker(server);
var tree = dw.DiscoverDependencies(new SqlSmoObject[] {tbl}, DependencyType.Children);
var cur = tree.FirstChild.FirstChild;
while (cur != null)
{
    var table = server.GetSmoObject(cur.Urn) as Table;
    if (table != null && table.ForeignKeys.Cast<ForeignKey>().Any(fk => fk.ReferencedTable == tbl.Name))
    {
        //do something with table.Name
    }
    cur = cur.NextSibling;
}
```