# How to Drop a SQL foreign constraint by column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-key-relationship, sql-drop

We have many DB's that are identical schema, but the FK names might not be.
We do a lot of cloning for testing and such.

Ran into a problem with the clone when we added a self referencing Foreign Key.
We can't go back and change all the older DB's, but just need a way to clone and skip past the constraint, and re apply at the end.

```
// Keeping the columns simplified to just the 2 main ones causing the issue.

Table [Employee]

Columns [EmpId(pk), ManagerId(fk)]

ManagerId --> EmpId
```

So, if the clone trys to insert the Employee wiht a managerId that does not exist, you get an FK error.

Found several ways to Alter(drop then add) or rename the FK, but i need to know at cone application run time the FK's name, so i can alter.

Please no lectures on cloning, or copying, or why we're doing things wrong.
We did multi DB's this way and self referencing for internal reasons.

Comment: Or just disable all the contraints.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

What i came up with.

I can get the `FK NAME` and then `ALTER` the constraint, do my operations, then reapply it.

```
DECLARE @fkname VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Command_drop NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Command_add NVARCHAR(1000)

    --GET THE FK NAME by column Names
    -- thanks to marc_s https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907957/295734
SELECT  @fkname = fk.name
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
                                     AND fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
                                     AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
WHERE   fkc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.employee')
        AND c1.name = 'manager_employee_id'
        AND c2.name = 'id'

SET @Command_drop = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @fkname
SET @Command_add = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT ' + @fkname
    + ' FOREIGN KEY (manager_employee_id) REFERENCES Employee(id)'
    -- DROP the constraint
EXEC (@Command_drop)
    -- DO SOME OPERATION HERE --
    -- Re ADD the constraint
EXEC (@Command_add)
```

**OR**

[Disable All Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)

**OR**

change alter to - untested

disable:

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtable_Name> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT <yourconstraint_Name>
```

enable:

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtable_Name> CHECK CONSTRAINT <yourconstraint_Name>
```

Comment: This also keeps the FK the same name, so anything else referencing it, will not have to be changed.