# How to get a list of all tables used in a specific column in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `users` : `id`,`name`, etc...

I want to get a list of all tables,views that use `users.id`

for example if table `user_new` is refrencing `users.id` as `FK` I want it to be desplayed in the query.

How do I do that?

Comment: If this is a one-off check, the easiest way is to run `BEGIN; ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN id; ROLLBACK;`. The `DROP` should fail, and the referencing constraints and views will be reported in the error message.

Comment: @NickBarnes It's really a bad idea !!

Answer (score 2):

Use [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-depend.html).

Example:

```
create table some_table (
    id serial primary key);

create table child_table (
    id int, 
    master_id int references some_table(id));

create view some_view as 
    select * from some_table;

select distinct pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid)
from pg_depend 
where refobjid = 'some_table'::regclass

                     pg_describe_object
------------------------------------------------------------
 sequence some_table_id_seq
 constraint some_table_pkey on table some_table
 type some_table
 default for table some_table column id
 constraint child_table_master_id_fkey on table child_table
 rule _RETURN on view some_view
(6 rows)
```

The above query selects all objects referencing to `some_table`. 
You can filter the result for a specific column and/or desired type of relationship.
To select only tables and views depending on the first column, use:

```
select distinct pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid)
from pg_depend
where 
    refobjid = 'some_table'::regclass 
    and refobjsubid = 1 -- only for column #1
    and deptype = 'n'; -- a normal relationship between separately-created objects

                     pg_describe_object
------------------------------------------------------------
 constraint child_table_master_id_fkey on table child_table
 rule _RETURN on view some_view
(2 rows)
```

Comment: The query in my answer selects **all** objects referencing to `some_table`. Of course, you can filter the result for a desired type of object.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT conrelid::regclass table_name
    FROM pg_constraint c
    WHERE c.confrelid = 'user'::regclass::oid
        AND c.confkey @> (
            SELECT array_agg(attnum)
            FROM pg_attribute
            WHERE attname = 'id'
                AND attrelid = c.confrelid
            )
        AND contype = 'f'
```

---

As per [PostgreSQL Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

**pg_constraint** **:**

> *The catalog pg_constraint stores check, primary key, unique, foreign*
>   *key, and exclusion constraints on tables*
>
> **contype** : - c = check constraint, ***f = foreign key constraint***, p = primary key constraint, u = unique constraint, t = constraint trigger,
>   x = exclusion constraint,
>   **conrelid** : The table this constraint is on,
>   **confrelid** : If a foreign key, the referenced table,
>   **conkey** : If a table constraint (including foreign keys, but not constraint triggers), list of the constrained columns

Refer [Object Identifier Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html) for `oid` and `regclass`

Comment: is there a way to get the column_name along with the table_name ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use information_schema

for views:

`select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.views where view_definition ilike '%users.id%';`

for tables:

`select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and column_name='id';`

Comment: The second query only shows the PK field. To get the FK fields, you need to use `information_schema.referential_constraints`; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907879/sql-server-howto-get-foreign-key-reference-from-information-schema)