# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK._.."

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

Is there a way to see the ID of the row that is conflicting? I am using SQL Server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907999/3270427

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I did not express myself the best way. So I know the table and column name, but I want to know the exact row where the DELETE statement is failing. I understood from a friend that you can in MySQL but he didn't know if you can in SQL Server.