# Script all objects in a database into a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to populate a table in SQL server 2005 with some objects in a particular database (stored procedures, tables, views and functions, etc)

In the table I would like one line per object and the table columns will be the name of the object , the script of the object, schema and object type.

I have tried to use the script below but this does not return script for tables. 
Is there a way to return all objects with its scripts?

```
    select a.name, * 
from 
    Enterprise..sysobjects a 
    inner join Enterprise..syscomments b on a.id=b.id 
where
    a.xtype in ('FN','IF','P','TF','TR','U','V','X')
```

Comment: All of that data will already be in the database in the systems tables. What do you need to do this for?

Comment: Basically I want store the create-table script for the tables in my own table. Similar to the create-procedure scipts that i copied to my own tables that was held in the sysobjects table. We will be using this to track changes that are made in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scripting tables is difficult, look here: [In MSSQL, how do I generate a CREATE TABLE statement for a given table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-mssql-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table)

you best bet might be to make a CLR that uses SMO to generate the scripts, see:[Scripting Database Objects using SMO](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated)

If you just want to track the database changes, possibly a DDL trigger to log changes, see: [Using DDL Triggers to Manage SQL Server 2005](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3552096/Using-DDL-Triggers-to-Manage-SQL-Server-2005.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a database (plus web app) which tracks changes in other databases, [dbscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/dbscript-new-version-0-99/) might help. (disclaimer: I wrote it ;))