# Generating create table script (with indexes, keys, constrains) for all tables in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2005

If I run the following script

```
SELECT so.Name, sc.Text
FROM syscomments sc JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.ID = so.ID
```

I will get all the create procedure/function scripts. Is there something like this for tables, indexes, keys, and triggers?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate script of all indexes, keys in the SQL Server database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610288/generate-script-of-all-indexes-keys-in-the-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing inbuilt.

To do it in T-SQL You'd need to find or write your own script. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table/21551#21551) that might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL 2012 and later use this

I have tried many scripts in web. All of them had flaws. I finally wrote my script using a post in msdn site and changed it to work on many kind of situations.

Note: This scripts works on SQL Server 2012 and later

```
WITH IndexInfo AS (
SELECT ix.object_id
    , ix.NAME AS IndexName
    , ix.type_desc
    , ix.filter_definition
    , ix.is_unique
    , ix.is_primary_key
    , ix.allow_row_locks
    , ix.allow_page_locks
    , ds.NAME AS DataSpaceName
    , ds.type AS DataSpaceType
    , ix.is_padded
    , object_schema_name(ix.object_id) AS SchemaName
    , object_name(ix.object_id) AS TableName
    , IIF(ix.type <= 2, is_included_column, 0) AS HasIncludedColumn
    , IIF(ix.type in (5, 6), 1, 0) AS IsColumnStore
    , (
        SELECT KeyColumns
        FROM (
            SELECT IC2.object_id
                , IC2.index_id
                , STUFF((
                        SELECT ' , ' + C.NAME + IIF(MAX(CONVERT(INT, IC1.is_descending_key)) = 1 AND ix.type <= 2, ' DESC ', ' ')
                        FROM sys.index_columns IC1
                        JOIN sys.columns C ON C.object_id = IC1.object_id
                            AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id
                            --AND IC1.is_included_column = 0   
                            AND IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.is_included_column, 0) = 0
                            AND IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.key_ordinal, ic.index_column_id) > 0
                        WHERE IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id
                            AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id
                        GROUP BY IC1.object_id
                            , C.NAME
                            , index_id
                            , IC1.key_ordinal
                            , IC1.index_column_id
                        ORDER BY IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.key_ordinal, IC1.index_column_id)
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') KeyColumns
            FROM sys.index_columns IC2
            GROUP BY IC2.object_id
                , IC2.index_id
            ) tmp
        WHERE tmp.object_id = ix.object_id
            AND tmp.index_id = ix.index_id
        ) AS KeyColumnsStr
    , (
        SELECT IncludedColumns
        FROM (
            SELECT IC2.object_id, IC2.index_id
                , STUFF((
                        SELECT ' , ' + C.NAME
                        FROM sys.index_columns IC1
                        JOIN sys.columns C ON C.object_id = IC1.object_id
                            AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id
                            --AND IC1.is_included_column = 1   
                            AND IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.is_included_column, 0) <> 0
                        WHERE IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id
                            AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id
                        --and IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.key_ordinal, ic.index_column_id) > 0
                        GROUP BY IC1.object_id, C.NAME, index_id, IC1.key_ordinal, IC1.index_column_id
                        ORDER BY IIF(ix.type <= 2, IC1.key_ordinal, IC1.index_column_id)
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') IncludedColumns
            FROM sys.index_columns IC2
            GROUP BY IC2.object_id, IC2.index_id
            ) tmp
        WHERE tmp.object_id = ix.object_id
            AND tmp.index_id = ix.index_id
            AND IncludedColumns IS NOT NULL
        ) AS IncludedColumnsStr
FROM sys.indexes ix
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.index_id = ix.index_id AND ic.object_id = ix.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON col.column_id = ic.column_id AND col.object_id = ix.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces ds ON ix.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
WHERE ix.NAME IS NOT NULL AND IIF(ix.type <= 2, ic.key_ordinal, ic.index_column_id) > 0
)
, Scrpt AS (
SELECT *
    , 'CREATE ' 
    + CASE WHEN is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END 
    + type_desc COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' INDEX ' + IndexName + ' ON ' 
        + SchemaName + '.' + TableName + '(' + KeyColumnsStr + ')' 
    + ISNULL(IIF(HasIncludedColumn > 0, ' ', ' INCLUDE (' + IncludedColumnsStr + ')'), '') 
    + IIF(filter_definition IS NULL, ' ', ' WHERE ' + filter_definition) 
    + ' WITH (' 
        + CASE WHEN IsColumnStore = 1 THEN ' DROP_EXISTING = OFF '
          ELSE
                IIF(is_padded = 1, ' PAD_INDEX = ON ', ' PAD_INDEX = OFF ') + ',' 
                + ' DROP_EXISTING = OFF ' + ',' 
                + ' ONLINE = OFF ' + ',' 
                + IIF(allow_row_locks = 1, ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON ', ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF ') + ',' 
                + IIF(allow_page_locks = 1, ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ', ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF ') 
          END
        + ' ) ' 
    + IIF(DataSpaceType = 'FG','ON [' + DataSpaceName + ']', '') AS CreateIndexScript
FROM IndexInfo
)
SELECT DISTINCT IndexName, CreateIndexScript
FROM Scrpt
WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.SWPartition')
```

As a credit to original author, I mentions the original link here 
[How to Generate Index Creation Scripts](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19598.how-to-generate-index-creation-scripts-for-all-tables-in-a-database-using-t-sql.aspx)