# Not able to see triggers after publish database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I created some triggers in SQL Server 2012.

Now I create a `Generate` scripts but I can not see triggers after publish

Comment: When you generated the script - did you choose to **include** the triggers? $

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate Scripts For All Triggers in Database Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200511/how-to-generate-scripts-for-all-triggers-in-database-using-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers are not scripted by default - you have to **include** them specifically!

On the `Generate and Publish Scripts` dialog, you need to click on the `Advanced` button and in the dialog that pops up, you need to select `Script triggers` and set it to `TRUE` (it's `FALSE` by default):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you used Management Studio to generate your scripts, then you likely didn't set the option to include triggers on script generation.

Look under Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting -> Script Triggers

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326600.aspx for reference and default values.