# How to get table create script dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I need to get the table create script through query.is this possible to get script by passing table and database name as variables..

Comment: The question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213687/how-to-generate-create-script-of-table-using-sql-query-in-sql-server

Comment: @rverdelli I already seen this one. My requirement is both table name and database name I'm trying to pass as an input parameter it should return script..the page you mentioned in the above we can't pass the database name ...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this TSQL

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME

SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.tablename'

DECLARE @object_name SYSNAME
    ,@object_id INT

SELECT @object_name = '[' + s.NAME + '].[' + o.NAME + ']'
    ,@object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.NAME + '.' + o.NAME = @table_name
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH index_column
AS (
    SELECT ic.[object_id]
        ,ic.index_id
        ,ic.is_descending_key
        ,ic.is_included_column
        ,c.NAME
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
        AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
    )
    ,fk_columns
AS (
    SELECT k.constraint_object_id
        ,cname = c.NAME
        ,rcname = rc.NAME
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id
        AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id
        AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
    )
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
            SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.NAME + '] ' + CASE 
                    WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                        THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition]
                    ELSE UPPER(tp.NAME) + CASE 
                            WHEN tp.NAME IN (
                                    'varchar'
                                    ,'char'
                                    ,'varbinary'
                                    ,'binary'
                                    ,'text'
                                    )
                                THEN '(' + CASE 
                                        WHEN c.max_length = - 1
                                            THEN 'MAX'
                                        ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5))
                                        END + ')'
                            WHEN tp.NAME IN (
                                    'nvarchar'
                                    ,'nchar'
                                    ,'ntext'
                                    )
                                THEN '(' + CASE 
                                        WHEN c.max_length = - 1
                                            THEN 'MAX'
                                        ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5))
                                        END + ')'
                            WHEN tp.NAME IN (
                                    'datetime2'
                                    ,'time2'
                                    ,'datetimeoffset'
                                    )
                                THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                            WHEN tp.NAME = 'decimal'
                                THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                            ELSE ''
                            END + CASE 
                            WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
                                THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name
                            ELSE ''
                            END + CASE 
                            WHEN c.is_nullable = 1
                                THEN ' NULL'
                            ELSE ' NOT NULL'
                            END + CASE 
                            WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL
                                THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition]
                            ELSE ''
                            END + CASE 
                            WHEN ic.is_identity = 1
                                THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')'
                            ELSE ''
                            END
                    END + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id]
                AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0
                AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id
                AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1
                AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
                AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ') + ISNULL((
            SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.NAME + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + (
                    SELECT STUFF((
                                SELECT ', [' + c.NAME + '] ' + CASE 
                                        WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1
                                            THEN 'DESC'
                                        ELSE 'ASC'
                                        END
                                FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                                JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
                                    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                                WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                    AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id
                                    AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id
                                FOR XML PATH(N'')
                                    ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                    ) + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'
            ), '') + ')' + CHAR(13) + ISNULL((
            SELECT (
                    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' + CASE 
                            WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1
                                THEN ' NOCHECK'
                            ELSE ' CHECK'
                            END + ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.NAME + '] FOREIGN KEY(' + STUFF((
                                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                                FROM fk_columns k
                                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                    ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')' + ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.NAME + '] (' + STUFF((
                                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                                FROM fk_columns k
                                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                    ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')' + CASE 
                            WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1
                                THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE'
                            WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2
                                THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                            WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3
                                THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT'
                            ELSE ''
                            END + CASE 
                            WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1
                                THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                            WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2
                                THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                            WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3
                                THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'
                            ELSE ''
                            END + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.NAME + ']' + CHAR(13)
                    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
                    JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
                    WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
                    FOR XML PATH(N'')
                        ,TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ), '') + ISNULL((
            (
                SELECT CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE 
                        WHEN i.is_unique = 1
                            THEN ' UNIQUE'
                        ELSE ''
                        END + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.NAME + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' + STUFF((
                            SELECT ', [' + c.NAME + ']' + CASE 
                                    WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1
                                        THEN ' DESC'
                                    ELSE ' ASC'
                                    END
                            FROM index_column c
                            WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                                AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                                ,TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')' + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + STUFF((
                                SELECT ', [' + c.NAME + ']'
                                FROM index_column c
                                WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                    ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '') + CHAR(13)
                FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
                WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
                    AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                    AND i.[type] = 2
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ), '')

PRINT @SQL
```