# Query a postgres database for the SQL which generates the tables

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication

We want to replicate our local test DB automatically, given the structure of the production DB, on the fly / on demand.

What would be nice, would be to query the prod DB and retrieve the SQL that generates the tables/views and then run that SQL against a cleaned out local DB.

Or perhaps there is a better way to replicate a production DB on a local machine?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate create script of table using SQL query in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213687/how-to-generate-create-script-of-table-using-sql-query-in-sql-server)

Comment: @johan855: Not a duplicate. Postgres is not SQL Server .

Comment: You are approaching this from the wrong end. Your production database should have been created from SQL scripts stored in a version control system - including all schema changes. If you need to setup a test database, run those scripts from the version control system. Tools like Liquibase or Flyway will help you organize and track the execution of those scripts

Comment: @horse i sort of disagree - the truth ultimate lies in the DB itself not in VCS, there is no need to put SQL in VCS, that might be overkill?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correct, you need to copy DB schema. You can use `pg_dump` with `--schema-only` parameter to do this. It'll only dump schema of the database, and you can import it locally.

```
$ pg_dump mydb --schema-only > mydb-schema.sql
```