# Create Table from View

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

I have a view that I want to create a table from in SQL Enterprise Manager, but I always get an error when I run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
AS
(SELECT top 10 FROM dbo.myView)
```

So far the error is: "syntax error at 'as'"

View is too large. Is it possible to use a top 10?

Comment: And *what error do you get*?!

Comment: what error are you getting when you try this?

Comment: select * into A from dbo.myView where 1 = 2 will give you an empty table

Comment: Your question answered on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table). [See this answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317864/4104167).
script on this answer get you scripts for generate all tables in database. If you modify last where condition, you can get scripts for create table from views. [The next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551/4104167) makes it easier for you. You can set table or view name and run script then result return create table script for you.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`SQL Server` does not support `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`.

Use this:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    A
FROM    myview
```

or

```
SELECT  TOP 10
        *
INTO    A
FROM    myview
ORDER BY
        id
```

Comment: VIews to big to select *. How can I say top 10?

Comment: Is there any way to prevent a connection timeout without limiting results with this method?

Comment: @vizyourdata: run it as an SQL Server agent job

Comment: good one but the one below is better if you dont need the data, just the schema

Answer (score 61):

If you just want to snag the schema and make an empty table out of it, use a false predicate,  like so:

```
SELECT * INTO myNewTable FROM myView WHERE 1=2
```

Comment: ... WHERE false; work fine.

Answer (score 14):

In SQL SERVER you do it like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO A
FROM dbo.myView
```

This will create a new table `A` with the contents of your view.
See [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

To create a table on the fly us this syntax:

```
SELECT *
INTO A
FROM dbo.myView
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a new `A` you can use `INTO`;

```
select * into A from dbo.myView
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * INTO [table_a] FROM dbo.myView
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks a lot like Oracle, but that doesn't work on SQL Server.

You can, instead, adopt the following syntax...

```
SELECT
  *
INTO
  new_table
FROM
  old_source(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    MonthEndDate MED,  
    SUM(GrossBalance/1000000) GrossBalance,
    PortfolioRename PR 
into 
    testDynamic 
from 
    Risk_PortfolioOverview  
    Group By MonthEndDate, PortfolioRename
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO table 2
SELECT * FROM table1/view1
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: This will insert rows in to an existing table, not create a new table.