# SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table. I need to create the same table in another database.
How would I see what the Create Table query was that created the table so I can just run that.

```
    CREATE TABLE ..
```

Comment: Take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table

Comment: Do you really want the exact same table in another database?  If there are FKs that could be a problem.  It might be easier to query into the existing database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSMS you can right click the table and select Script Table as Create to New Query Window.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume SQL Server 2005 or greater, since you did not specify. In Management Studio, simply right-click on the table, select Script Table As --> Drop and Create --> To New Query Editor Window.

For SQL Server 2000, in Enterprise Manager, right-click the table and you'll have a similar option to script the table creation to a file. I forget the exact menu option text, but it's easy enough.