# Why the table sys.sql_modules is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SSMS, I create a database using the following script. When the script execution completes, I would expect to see the CREATE TABLE statement in the [sql_modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) table. However I can't find it.

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDb]
GO 
USE [MyDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [UID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Here's the query I run the get the table definition. However, I get three empty result sets. Any idea why I am getting those three empty results set?

```
USE MyDb
GO

SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_modules

SELECT * 
FROM sys.triggers

SELECT sm.object_id, OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS object_name, o.type, o.type_desc, sm.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
ORDER BY o.type;
```

Comment: Are you creating any procedures, functions, views? tables don't show up there. [The first paragraph here says what to expect to find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx)

Comment: Where would I find the table definitions?

Comment: You need to figure them out yourself from the other views. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317864/73226) or you can use SMO to script them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get columns and table information, this is a good place to start:

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch ON t.schema_id = sch.schema_id
WHERE sch.name = 'dbo'
   AND t.name = 'YourTable'
```