# How To Get 'Create Table' script for a table or sp using vb6 with sql server 2000

Tags: sql, vb6

I need the "create table... " statement for a particular table and stored procedure to recreate them in another database. Forget the backup and restore. I have to do it in vb6. Its the same thing you get when you copy the Table And paste it in query analyzer. Its sql server 2000
Edit: Now I Know it can be asked as 'How To Script Entire Database Through VB6'.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [StackOverlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table) which talks about the same.  Although it is not VB6-specific, you should be able to apply this solution without a problem.

Essentially you create a stored procedure that will generate the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the given table.  The stored procedure will examine the `sysobjects` table to build the SQL.

Your VB6 application can run the stored procedure on server 'A' fetching the `CREATE TABLE` SQL. Then connect to server 'B' and run that SQL to create the table on the other server.