# Possible to query the create script for an XML Schema Collection?

Tags: sql-server, xml-schema-collection

As a first step to adding our SQL objects to version control I've written a script that will query `sys.objects`, `sys.modules` to script out all objects as `CREATE`s.  I used an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table) to script out my tables.  The goal is to preserve the change history of our SQL objects and eventually automate SQL steps we currently achieve manually.  Now I need to script out `XMLSchemaCollections` as a `CREATE` but I haven't had luck finding an example of how.  I imagine it would include querying the several `sys.xml_schema_*` tables and piecing the `XML` together element by agonizing element.  Does anyone have a working example of how to achieve this?

NOTE: The requirement is to achieve this through a SQL script, not a 3rd party component (i.e. RedGate) nor a Visual Studio Database Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [xml_schema_namespace (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190316.aspx)

> Reconstructs all the schemas or a specific schema in the specified XML
>   schema collection.

Comment: I knew there was a simple way!  I'm ashamed I wasn't able to connect the dots myself.  Thanks.