# Create new table schema from existing table without using select into

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need to copy data from on premise sql server to sql azure, but as sql azure does not support select into, so I need to first create table on sql azure and then call insert into. Here, I do not know source table to migrate, so how can I create new table's schema definition using existing ones?

Comment: You can use the Generate Scripts tool in SSMS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx

Comment: I do not want to do manually, script should be created via code.

Comment: What is the use case that you're trying to meet here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table

Comment: Select into is supported by sql dB v12, give a shot.

Comment: Select into is supported in V12

Comment: My server is V12, it is not working. When I do select @@version, it gives me "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Mar 30 2016 13:04:43 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation"