# Generate Scripts equivalent in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am not sure if there's an equivalent TSQL script for this.

I want to Generate Scripts using TSQL code similar to how backup and others items work in SSMS

for example in backup
[image]

clicking the script action it will generate this tsql script

`BACKUP DATABASE [prosmartexamples.prosmarttools] TO  DISK = N'D:\Backup\example.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'example.test-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO`

Now, I want it also to work the same in Generate Scripts but I dont know how to get the equivalent of it in TSQL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Script ...` scripts current action that was perfromed in GUI, here taking backup.

`Generate Scripts` from object explorer was designed to script database objects(tables, views, functions,...).

---

> [Get script for every action in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2179/get-script-for-every-action-in-sql-server-management-studio/)
>
> SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) provides a very good option to generate scripts for any operation performed through the GUI. It is an effective way to save the T-SQL code of actions performed through SSMS. Here is list of some of the tasks categories for which you may generate T-SQL scripts from SSMS GUI actions
>
> - Changing any server instance level option
> - Changing any database level option
> - Managing server roles, logins, permissions
> - Managing database roles, users, permissions
> - Backup/Restore operations
> - Managing policies (SQL Server 2008)
>
> [Generate Scripts (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> You can create scripts for multiple objects by using the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard. **You can also generate a script for individual objects or multiple objects by using the Script as menu in Object Explorer.**

Comment: i dont get what do you want to say

Comment: @SecretCoder Long story short action(backup) != object(table)

Comment: so what you mean is it is not possible to in TSQL to generate a script. because I want to transfer data for whole tables in my existing database to a new database with the same structure using code either TSQL or C#

Comment: @SecretCoder It is a XY Problem then. Please extend your question. You have multiple options: backupt/restore, generating dacpac/bacpac file, SSIS, script table objects ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for this option:

it generate the schema of database along with the data in `T-SQL` format.

[image]

or if your looking just the script of *Generate Script* task i think, that's not possible. Alternatively, you can try following (unfortunately User tables not extractable in this method), [for tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317864/6598234):

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() as DBName, o.object_id, OBJECT_NAME (o.object_id) as ObjectName,
        type_desc,
        OBJECT_DEFINITION (o.object_id) as ObjectDefination
FROM sys.objects as o
where o.type in ('V', 'P', 'TR')
go
```